# How to get count of CTE result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, common-table-expression

I am new to sql, I have created a CTE now I want to get the count of rows from CTE result set

```
DECLARE @start_date date,@end_date DATE ;

select @start_date= min(ETA) from  [dbo].[testTable]
        select @end_date=max(ETA) from  [dbo].[testTable];

    ;WITH  AllDays
              AS ( 
              SELECT   @start_date AS [Date]
              --, 1 AS [level]
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT   DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
                   --, [level] + 1
                   FROM     AllDays
                   WHERE    [Date] < @end_date )
                   --Insert into #tempETA (CallETA) 
         SELECT [Date]--, [level]
         FROM   AllDays  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

         select count(a.Date),a.Date from AllDays a
```

I am getting error here:

```
(1048 row(s) affected)
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
Invalid object name 'AllDays'.
```

Comment: `SELECT [Date]--, [level] , (select count([Date]) FROM AllDays a)      FROM   AllDays`. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I want to get the count of rows which are in 'AllDays'  see this line, 'select count(a.Date),a.Date from AllDays a ' I am getting error here

Comment: this is just an example code, In my real code there are some select statements which return a set of rows in CTE , and I have to get the count of rows, but when I do select count(Id) from CTE it gives me error: Invalid object name CTE

Comment: Decide: what shall your results contain? The dates? The count? The dates and the count per date? So far you are kind of mixing the three. With SQL questions it's always good advice to show sample data and expexted results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `CTE` can hold temporary result set that is defined within the execution scope of a single `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE`. You cannot have another `SELECT` outside the scope of `CTE`

Use `@@ROWCOUNT` to get the count of `CTE`. Considering you want the `CTE` result and its count.

```
SELECT [Date]--, [level]
FROM   AllDays  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

select @@ROWCOUNT
```

If you want to count to be part of your result then use `COUNT() OVER()`

```
SELECT [Date],count(1)over() as Total_count
FROM   AllDays  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: yes @@RowCount does the trick. But why I am not able to access the CTE object like 'select count(a.Date),a.Date from AllDays a '

Comment: @RKSharma - Because a CTE can end with a single `SELECT`

Answer (score 1):

Check out this below code and tell.is this what you want to get.?

```
DECLARE @start_date date,@end_date DATE ;

select @start_date= min(ETA) from  [dbo].[testTable]
        select @end_date=max(ETA) from  [dbo].[testTable];

    ;WITH  AllDays
              AS ( 
              SELECT   @start_date AS [Date]
              --, 1 AS [level]
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT   DATEADD(DAY, 1, @start_date)
                   --, [level] + 1
                   FROM     [testTable]
                   WHERE    @start_date < @end_date )
                   --Insert into #tempETA (CallETA) 
         --SELECT [Date]--, [level]
         --FROM   AllDays  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

         select count(a.Date) from AllDays a
```

Comment: appreciate your efforts but you have changed the code,   you have used 'testTable' instead of 'AllDays' in CTE, so it changed the scenario. Thanks by the way